# RSpec: Using view.should_receive with subject

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, rspec, rspec-rails

Any ideas why this works:

```
it {view.should_receive(:update_method)}
```

but this doesn't?:

```
subject { view }
it { should_receive(:update_method) }
```

Everything else being the same.  I get this error:

```
Failure/Error: it {should_receive(:update_method) 
(#<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1:0x7faf27602d58>).update_method
    expected: 1 time
    received: 0 times
```

But I don't know what RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested.... is referring to.  Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the second time this has come up in 24 hours. Something's in the air. See https://github.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/issues/148 for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks.  That clears things up.  It's good to be redirected before I had a chance to abuse the after hook for too long.  I looked up mock expectations, but can't really grasp the difference between should_receive vs the other should expectations.  Any quick pointers on this?  Thanks again and take care!

Comment: what are good examples of "post-example clean up".  I can't think of when to rightfully use the after hook.  Rollback database modifications?  Thanks again!